# Only seeing default gateway in arp table and not dns server ip, why?

Tags: dns, ip, arp

When I use the command ipconfig /all, I get the IP's of default gateway and DNS server. Then I connect to a website and use the arp -a command to view the arp table. On the table I only see the default gateway IP, below the Internet address and I can't see anywhere the DNS server IP. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll only ever see ARP entries for addresses *on the same subnet*. Devices outside the subnet are, by definition, only reachable through a gateway and not directly at MAC layer.

So if you're using an off-subnet DNS server (like the one provided by your ISP), the computer won't even try resolving it through ARP. Instead, packets going to it will have the *local gateway's* MAC address as the destination.